# Inertia Laravel Vue with SSR

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

Good evening, in our project that uses Laravel 10, Vue 3, composer 2, we have mounted inertia 1.0. The need is to start the project with SSR. In all cases by issuing the two commands

```
npm run dev
```

and

```
php artisan inertia:start-ssr
```

we received the response

```
{"status":"NOT_FOUND","timestamp":1697208690854}
```

By launching php artisan serve and npm run dev the project starts without problems, but does not enable SSR